# Display the address of the last non-empty cell (if values are not unique)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
             A                             B       C      D      E       F

1 |                                     |  Jan.   Feb.   March   April   May 
2 | Profit                              |   100    200    200    
3 | Cell Reference last non-empty cell  |   ??
```

In **Row 2** you can find the profit for each month. In **Cell B3** I want to to display the address of the **last non-empty cell** in **Row 2**. For this I tried the following formula:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B2),MATCH((IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A2:$F2<>0),$A2:$F2),0)),$A2:$F2,0),4,1)
```

This formula works perfectly if all the numbers in **Row 2** are **unique**. However, in my example above you can see that the profit in `Februay` equals the profit in `March`; therefore, the formula above gives me the address `C2` instead of `D2`.

What do I have to change in my formula to **always** get the address of the **last non-empty cell** no matter if it is unique or not?

Comment: Whenever someone wants the address I always ask why?  Are you going to use it in another formula to return a value?  If so we can skip this step completely and it would be much easier.  So is the address the final outcome?

Comment: Hi Scott, in the end I will use it in another formula. I think I might post another question with the final desired outcome but so far you already helped me a lot with your answer below.

Comment: then skip the whole address and just use the MATCH part in an INDEX formula.  ADDRESS is volatile and not needed in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B2),MATCH(1E+99,$A2:$F2),4,1)
```

Which will return the last cell with a number in that range.

For text and numbers:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B2),MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,$A2:$F2),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",$A2:$F2),0)),4,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there also way to get the same result no matter if the last value is a number or a text?

Comment: Somehow the second formula gives me the error "You've entered too many arguments for this function" but I cannot find the error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Works for me see photo.

Comment: Ah sorry I typed something wrong. Now it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
=ADDRESS(2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(2:2),0,0),0)-1)
```

[image]

NOTE:

1. will handle either text or numbers, unique or not
2. is not an array formula
3. data must be compact....no empties in the middle

The last restriction is important because the formula relies on finding the first empty in the row and taking one step back!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following array formula:

```
= ADDRESS(ROW(B2),MAX(COLUMN(2:2)*NOT(ISBLANK(2:2))))
```

This returns the address of the last non-empty cell in the 2nd row.

Note this is an array formula, so you muse press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard when entering this formula rather than just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I agree with @ScottCraner that returning the address usually isn't useful. If you are planning on using this value, as part of another formula, you should **not** do this:

```
= INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B2),MAX(COLUMN(2:2)*NOT(ISBLANK(2:2)))))
```

Instead, skip using `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` altogether and instead use `INDEX` to get the value in that cell, i.e.

```
= INDEX(2:2,MAX(COLUMN(2:2)*NOT(ISBLANK(2:2)))))
```