# Display the address of the last non-empty cell in a column (if values are not unique)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B                C
1     Month     Profit      
2     Jan.        100             Cell Reference last non-empty cell
3     Feb.        200             ??
4     Mar.        300
5     Apr.        300
6
7
```

In `Column B` you can find the profit for each month. In `Cell C3` I want to to display the address of the last non-empty cell in `Column B`. In this case it would be `B5`. For this I tried to modify the formular from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016315/display-the-address-of-the-last-non-empty-cell-if-values-are-not-unique)     question:

```
=ADDRESS(COLUMN(B2),MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,$B2:$B5),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",$B2:$B5),0)),4,1)
```

However, I could not make it work.

What do I have to change in my formula to always get the address of the last non-empty cell in `Column B` no matter if it is unique or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
="B"&MATCH(1E+99,B:B)
```

Comment: If you are going to use that in a indirect() there are better ways without the need of volatility.

Comment: Maybe you also have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610401/display-the-address-of-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-no-matter-if-column