# Display the address of the last non-empty cell in a column (no matter if column contains values or text)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A              B                      C
1     Product 01      Brand
2     Product 02      Brand A             Cell Reference last non-empty cell
3     Product 03      Brand A                 ??
4     Product 04      Brand B   
5     Product 05      Brand B
6     Product 06      Brand B
7
```

In `Column B` you can find the Brand for each Product. In `Cell C3` I want to to display the address of the last non-empty cell in `Column B`. In this case it would be `B5`. For this I tried to go with the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610137/display-the-address-of-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-if-values-are-not-un/57610180#57610180) question:

```
="B"&MATCH(1E+99,B:B)
```

However, this formula only works if `Column B` consists of values.

What do I have to change in the formula to always get the address of the last non-empty cell in `Column B` no matter if it's filled with values or text?

Comment: `="B"&MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,B:B),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",B:B),0))`

Comment: Would you have gaps in your data? If not I think `="B"&COUNTA(B:B)` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what about (as per my comment):

```
="B"&COUNTA(B:B)
```

Assuming you have a dataset without gaps.