# Get the column number of the last non-empty cell within a range (if values are not unique)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel-Spreadsheet:

```
     A  B  C    D       E       F       G      H     I      J     
1
2
3
4              200     150     80     300                   4
5              200     150     80     150                   2
6
7
```

In Range `J4:J5` I have the following formulas:

```
J4 = MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(D4:I4<>0),D4:I4),D4:I4,0)
J5 = MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(D4:I4<>0),D4:I4),D4:I4,0)
```

With this formula I want to identify the last non-empty cell within the range and get the the column number of it back. All this works perfectly in `Cell J4`.

However, in `Cell J5` I get back **number 2** instead of **number 4**. As far as I can see the reason for this is that in **Range D5:I5** the values are not unique (150 appears two times).

What do I need to change in my formula to always get the column number of the last non-empty cell no matter if the values are unique or not?

The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016315/display-the-address-of-the-last-non-empty-cell-if-values-are-not-unique) question does not help because my range is not starting in `Column A`. 
The range can be anywhere on the sheet.

Comment: Would there be gaps in your data? Say, `200,150,,300`. And are these actually formula results or just typed values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can adjust your existing `LOOKUP` function as follows:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D4:I4<>0),COLUMN(D4:I4)-MIN(COLUMN(D4:I4))+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Justyna for the answer. I think the nice part of this formula is that it even works in case there are words within the range.

Comment: True, it will also have these identified properly. Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: The other way around if you want to exclude the non-number values from it you can go with solution from Scott: =MATCH(1E+99,D4:I4)

Comment: The only thing I would do would be to replace the `-3` with `-MIN(COLUMN(D4:I4))+1`  Then if the range changes the user does not need to do the math, just change the range to match the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You only need MATCH:

```
=MATCH(1E+99,D4:I4)
```

if you are looking for text then:

```
=MATCH("zzz",D4:I4)
```

Or either:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,D4:I4),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",D4:I4),0))
```

[image]

---

The issue is that the LOOKUP returns the actual value, in the case of the error it returns 150 to the MATCH:

```
MATCH(150,D4:I4,0)
```

Which will return the first match location.