# Display the column number of the last non-empty cell within a range (if values are not unique)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
   A   B   C    D     E       F      G     H      I     J    K     L
1
2
3
4              600    150    80    600      0     0          4    
5              200    150    80     80      0     0          4
6
7
```

In Range `K4:K5` I currently use the formula from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874260/get-the-column-number-of-the-last-non-empty-cell-within-a-range-if-values-are-n) question to identify the last non-empty cell within the range and get the the column number of it back:

```
K4 = LOOKUP(2,1/(D4:J4<>0),COLUMN(D4:J4)-MIN(COLUMN(D4:J4))+1)
K5 = LOOKUP(2,1/(D5:J5<>0),COLUMN(D5:J5)-MIN(COLUMN(D5:J5))+1)
```

This formula works in the simple example above. However, once I use this formula in a bigger spreadsheet I get a lot of performance issues and numbers are not always updated correctly.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is alternative formula to get the column number of the last non-empty cell no matter if the values are unique or not?

Comment: Try this, I do not know if it is quicker than LOOKUP: `=AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN(D4:J4)-MIN(COLUMN(D4:J4))+1)/(D4:J4>0),1)`

Comment: Thanks Scott for this alternative solution. What about if I want to extract the value of the last non empty cell instead of the column number. Is there an easier solution?

Comment: use INDEX(): `=INDEX(D4:J4,AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN(D4:J4)-MIN(COLUMN(D4:J4))+1)/(D4:J4>0),1)` but we can simplify it to `=INDEX(A4:J4,AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN(D4:J4)/(D4:J4>0),1)`

Comment: Did the aggregate work for you?  Just curious if it resolved quicker than the Lookup.

Comment: It worked a bit quicker but no significantly. However,it is a huge file and a lot of rows to which I apply the formula so I am not sure if this evaluation is applicable for all cases.

Comment: Do you mean truly empty cells? or are values 0? And would you have 0s within the range, like> `10,20,30,0,10,0,0`?

Comment: All values are 0.

Comment: And about my other question?

Comment: There can also be 0s in the range.

Comment: In that case you can use any of the answers I gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58114629/9758194). Just change the criteria to: `D3:I3>0`, or whichever range you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already described in the comments below the question the following solutions are available:

**Option A)** 
If you want to get **column number** of the last non-empty cell:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN(D4:J4)-MIN(COLUMN(D4:J4))+1)/(D4:J4>0),1)
```

**Option B)** 
If you want go tet the **value** in the last non-empty cell:

```
=INDEX(D4:J4,AGGREGATE(14,7,(COLUMN(D4:J4)-MIN(COLUMN(D4:J4))+1)/(D4:J4>0),1)
=INDEX(A4:J4,AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN(D4:J4)/(D4:J4>0),1)
```