# Get the last column number of a search criteria in a defined range (if values are not unique)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
   A      B                  C          D       E       F      G        H        I  
1     Search Criteria:    Prod.B
2     Column:               2
3                                   Prod.A   Prod.B  Prod.B  Prod.C   Prod.C   Prod.D
4                      
5
```

Currently I use the following formula in `Cell C2` to get the column of the search criteria in `Cell C1` in the `Range D3:I3`.

```
=MATCH(C1,D3:H3,0)
```

All this works perfectly.

---

However, as you can see with the formula above I get back the first column number in which the search criteria appears.

What do I need to change in the formular to get the **last** column number in which the search criteria appears? *(In the example above it would be 3)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=MAX(IF(D3:I3=C1,COLUMN(D3:I3)-3))
```

Or:

```
=MATCH(2,1/(D3:I3=C1))
```

Enter both as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

***Alternatively:***

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D3:I3=C1),COLUMN(D3:I3)-3)
```

It should still be an array formula but you don't have to enter it as such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there also a formula without an array function?

Comment: @michi, not that I know of I'm afraid. Maybe a simple UDF